# ASP.NET MVC3 - Html.TextBoxFor and autofocus attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I generate the following `input` element using standard HTML helpers and Razor view engine:

```
<input id="Foo" name="Foo" type="text" autofocus />
```

Can I use the standard HTML helper or do I have to write my own?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can pass additional HTML attributes to the [TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703538.aspx) method:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo, new { autofocus="autofocus"})
```

Edit:
You can get only `autofocus=""` with:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo, new { autofocus=""})
```

All the built in helpers are using the [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx) class's [MergeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460515.aspx) method internally, and it only supports attributes in the following format : `key="value"`.
So if you need only `autofocus` you need to write your own helper with a custom html builder.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to generate `<input ... autofocus="autofocus" />`

Comment: In this case you need to implement your own helper, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what else has changed for MVC 4 regarding this scenario but I ended up using `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo, new { autofocus = true })`.

Answer (score 7):

I think autofocus="autofocus" is also valid see: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_autofocus.asp so you can use the htmlAttributes argument like so:

```
@Html.TextBox("Foo", null, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

### EDIT

I think you cannot use the standard HTML helpers if you really just want autofocus, you would have to do something like this:

```
@Html.Raw("<input id=\"Foo\" name=\"Foo\" type=\"text\" autofocus />")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to generate `<input ... autofocus="autofocus" />`

Comment: I edited my answer to show a method, but not using the standard TextBox, TextBoxFor stuff.  Can I ask why you do not want autofocus="autofocus"?